# How can I figure out whether a C# app was launched from the desktop or the cmd shell?

Tags: c#

How can i find out if a C# App has been started from the desktop or the cmd shell?

The msdn documentation is a bit fuzzy on this part. Perhaps someone can help me out here :)

Thx a lot!

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but why would this make a difference? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If i start the small app over the cmd shell, the output has to go to the shell window. If i start it over the desktop, i'll open a msgbox, show the result and copy it to the clipboard, if i press the correct button.

It's nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if(args[0] == "you exe name"){ ...}
```

If you double-click it, args[0] contains the full folder.

Note, you need to actually call `.GetCommandLineArgs()`, the `args[]` parameter that you have in a typical `static void Main(string[] args)` has this item removed.

-- Edit

This will only detect if it's run from the same path as the `.exe` itself. If you run it from a subfolder (`foo\hello.exe`) it won't work.

Comment: Also won't work if you actually specify the full path on the command-line.

Comment: Yes Tal: That's what I explained; the first parameter is what you type to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Try getting the parent process:

```
            var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process Id",
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        var p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pc.RawValue);
```

Not sure if this works when there are multiple instances of the same process, though. In such case it will be better to use this approach: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's not a way to know this, and that would be why the documentation is "fuzzy".

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation might be vague, but here's a straightforward way to find out if your C# application was started from the desktop or the command line:

```
if (Console.Title == System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) {
  Console.WriteLine("You clicked on this from Explorer, but this is a console app. Run it from a shell.");
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue (and have a great day)..."); Console.ReadKey(); return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Console app stuff MaxIsAwesome...");
```

When a C# console application is run from the command prompt, the Console.Title property is typically set to something like "Command Prompt - cmd.exe." However, if run by double-clicking from Explorer, the title is set to the application's full path, enabling differentiation between the two launch methods.  This is not foolproof but you can experiment and get something working for your specific project.  Good luck!

edit: although the question was posted 13yrs ago it wasn't answered and some replies suggested this was impossible.  It's not.  It is always better to answer things like this than leave them hanging.

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT to generate your original answer?